# Path-integral and measurements

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, path-integral, observables

I did a question a couple days ago and I didn't express it correctly. What happened is that i have a field obtained by solving the equations of motion of the $\lambda\phi^{4}$ theory. It was solved in the classical formalism. As I said, I learned how to utilize the canonical and the path-integral formalism to quantize a field. What i actually want to ask is, how can i obtain an observable through this field that i obtained. If it is, of course, possible. The solution (field) is of the form

$\phi(x,t) = f_{\epsilon}(t)\mathrm{e}^{i(\mathrm{k}x - \omega t)} + f_{0}(t)$

and what i initially tried was to try to transform this field into an operator $\phi(x,t) \rightarrow \hat{\phi}$,  by rewriting it whith some constant $B$ for normalization and in terms of the ladder operators $a(k),a^{\dagger}(k)$ or/and $b(k),b^{\dagger}(k)$. Then I realized it wasn't going very well and tried the path-integral formalism, and then things got confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/707205/2451

Comment: Hi gremory. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: this is not the same question